# PostGIS ST_SummaryStats

Tags: postgis-2.0

I need some help writing the sql for returning the "MEAN" value from a raster(in postgis db) that intersects a defined(inquery) polygon(in postgis db).

The polygon layer is called: public.farmpaddocks
The raster layer is called:  public.l8_9385_20131118ndvi_vg94
Both are SRID :3111

I have a field in the public.farmpaddocks table that I would like to filter the result on.
Field: farmpaddocks.farmid = '511'.

I assume i need to use the ST_Summarystats function? along with intersection and clip ??
This is my first attempt at an intersect. I get no error or result from the pgadmin output pane?? Not sure whats going on.

sql:

```
SELECT 
l8_9385_20131118ndvi_vg94.rast, 
farmpaddocks.farmid 
FROM 
public.l8_9385_20131118ndvi_vg94, 
public.farmpaddocks
WHERE
farmpaddocks.farmid='511' AND ST_Intersects(l8_9385_20131118ndvi_vg94.rast,
farmpaddocks.the_geom);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to read this http://www.gisintersect.com/?p=154 and understand how aggregate functions work, or this from [postgresql site](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-aggregate.html)

SQL from link:

```
SELECT gid, CAST(AVG(((foo.geomval).val)) AS decimal(9,3)) as avgimr FROM (SELECT p.gid, ST_Intersection(r.rast, p.cell) AS geomval FROM imrgrid2p5m r, priogrid_land p WHERE ST_Intersects(p.cell, r.rast)) AS foo WHERE (foo.geomval).val >=0 GROUP BY gid ORDER BY gid;
```

(see that AVG on start, replace that with your selected median aggregate function and you get median raster value inside polygon)

Then you need add Median support from [postgresql wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Aggregate_Median) or from install contrib package ( i dont know if there is already "default" package in contrib dir) or http://poststat.projects.pgfoundry.org/ or if you really need to math in postgis you can try PL/R from http://www.joeconway.com/plr/.

(disclaimer, i have newer actually used median function , poststat or PL/R and my experience with postgis raster is limited to import/export to db , but all given option should work )

Comment: Boston GIS has a nice, short PL/R tutorial and it includes how to build a median function for Postgres.  http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=postgresql_plr_tut01

Comment: Very coincidental "heyOverThere". Actually looking at an R script right now.....I was trying to figure out how to integrate R into my web application. You may have solved that problem for me with this method. Fantastic!!